# In the Prisoner of Azkaban movie, why was there no stag at the scene after Harry went back in time and saved himself?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, patronus-charm

In the movie, we can see a stag on the other side of the lake.

[image: 'Present' scene]

Shortly after, white light comes out of it and chases away the dementors.

[image: 'Present' scene #2]

However, in the 'future' scene, there is no stag whatsoever.

[image: 'Future' scene]

I know a stag is Harry's Patronus, but why did it appear on the screen beforehand and later on, we can only see 'future' Harry himself casting the charm - we see the scene from different perspectives for over 40 seconds, however, there is no stag on any of them.

Was 'present' Harry hallucinating?

Comment: It doesn't happen the same way in the novels, so I would say it was a director's decision to make the scene more impactful

Comment: @fez Which doesn't mean a director should abandon consistency during 'future' scene imo.

Comment: No definitely not, it would have been awesome seeing Harry react to the stag from the other side

Comment: @fez I'm not saying the stag should be removed - I think it should be added to the future scene to keep consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can see a stag if you look closely: it's a faint outline of the head with horns that pops in and out as he's casting it.

I just noticed it for the first time after seeing the movie for the 500th time.

[image: Harry Potter casting his Patronus]

It's pretty obvious once you're looking. In fact it's so obvious to me now I'm wondering if they added it in.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is done this way to bring focus to Harry, in this situation.

When Harry first sees the Patronus, he believes it was his Father (somehow), or maybe another member of his family, someone that Harry might be related to. And up until this point, Harry can't cast the Patronus Charm to save his life*.

So at this point, we are shown the Stag, to veil the mystery of the caster.

However, when Harry comes back later, he eventually realizes that it was not his Father, but actually himself, that was so successful in defeating the Dementors, and saving himself, and his new-found family (I.e. Sirius). Fueled by his faith in himself, inspired by the thought of his father and family, he casts the spell to great effect, for the first time.

In the movie, at this point we've already seen the stag, so this time we are focusing on Harry's success at finally overcoming his boundaries, and finally defeating the Dementors**.

Additionally, while I was greatly saddened to not see the Stag running rampant through the crowd of Dementors, like it says in the book, I believe there was some mention of "cutting expenses by limiting the animation of the Stag". (Don't quote me on that, not sure where I heard/read it).

<sup>* I'm always a fan of puns, but sometimes they just slip out unintentionally</sup>

<sup>** There may be a film trope for this, which you can ask over on [Movies.se](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, your last two paragraphs are an answer to my question (I understand why we can see the stag, I was asking why we can't see it in the future). However, I'd like some source for the explanation ("cutting expenses by limiting the animation of the Stag").

Comment: Unfortunately the only way we can get that answer is from an interview with the director/producers, with a very specific question, so I don't think that source would exist. (I did some googling and was unable to find anything myself).

Answer (score 0):

**He wasn't hallucinating as the observer.** The movie was slightly inconsistent with this detail, showing only pulsating light representing his patronus the second time. If anything you can call it a continuity error or a lack of precision in particularity.

The book illuminates things better:

> Facedown, too weak to move, sick and shaking, Harry opened his eyes. The Dementor must have released him. The blinding light was illuminating the grass around him… The screaming had stopped, the cold was ebbing away…
>
> Something was driving the Dementors back… It was circling around him and Black and Hermione… They were leaving…
>
> The air was warm again…
>
> With every ounce of strength he could muster, Harry raised his head a few inches and saw an animal amid the light, galloping away across the lake… Eyes blurred with sweat, Harry tried to make out what it was… It was as bright as a unicorn… Fighting to stay conscious, Harry watched it canter to a halt as it reached the opposite shore. For a moment, Harry saw, by its brightness, somebody welcoming it back… raising his hand to pat it… someone who looked
> strangely familiar… but it couldn’t be…
>
> > *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*
> >
> > Chapter 20, The Dementor's Kiss

And then he feints.

Later in the book, but only just, he travels back in time with Hermione and fulfills his role as the caster.

> “EXPECTO PATRONUM! ” he yelled.
>
> And out of the end of his wand burst, not a shapeless cloud of mist, but a blinding, dazzling, silver animal. He screwed up his eyes, trying to see what it was. It looked like a horse. It was galloping silently away from him, across the black surface of the lake. He saw it lower its head and charge at the swarming Dementors… Now it was galloping around and around the black shapes on the ground, and the Dementors were falling back, scattering, retreating into the darkness… They were gone.
>
> The Patronus turned. It was cantering back toward Harry across the still surface of the water. It wasn’t a horse. It wasn’t a unicorn, either. It was a stag. It was shining brightly as the moon above… it was coming back to him…
>
> > *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*
> >
> > Chapter 21, Hermione's Secret

To be fair, depicting this imagery of a spell in deer form running around bucking at dementors for the movie adaptation could have been mishandled, ponderous, or inelegant. The filmmakers decided to go the "bright waves of light" route, with Harry as an observer simply seeing the stag when the spell is initialized covering a figure behind it (and believing it's conjured by his dad). We don't see the stag during the second time for whatever reason. It might be so the audience attention is on caster Harry, for emotional effect, or it might purely be by mistake.

Either way, this isn't a question that's been asked to producer, screenwriter, director, or whoever on the crew staff would know, or published online AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks. So this was indeed an error. Once again, I didn't say a stag should 'run around bucking at dementors', I was only saying that a stag should stand still in front of Harry just as it was pictured in the 'present' scene.

Comment: I didn't imply that you said that. sorry if that's something you got out of my answer, but that's not what I was intending at all. I was giving credit to the filmmakers for not producing something much worse.